# Can't use facebook python sdk

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the SDK from http://github.com/pythonforfacebook in a new appengine project, but dev-appserver says that no module name facebook could be found.

Here is the code:

```
import facebook
import webapp2
import os
import jinja2
import urllib2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from webapp2_extras import sessions


FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "xxxxx"
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = "xxxxx"

config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = dict(secret_key='')

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    access_token = db.StringProperty(required=True)


class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """Provides access to the active Facebook user in self.current_user
    The property is lazy-loaded on first access, using the cookie saved
    by the Facebook JavaScript SDK to determine the user ID of the active
    user. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for
    more information.
    """
    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if self.session.get("user"):
            # User is logged in
            return self.session.get("user")
        else:
            # Either used just logged in or just saw the first page
            # We'll see here
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies,
                                                   FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                                                   FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
            if cookie:
                # Okay so user logged in.
                # Now, check to see if existing user
                user = User.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
                if not user:
                    # Not an existing user so get user info
                    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                    profile = graph.get_object("me")
                    user = User(
                        key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                        id=str(profile["id"]),
                        name=profile["name"],
                        profile_url=profile["link"],
                        access_token=cookie["access_token"]
                    )
                    user.put()
                elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                    user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                    user.put()
                # User is now logged in
                self.session["user"] = dict(
                    name=user.name,
                    profile_url=user.profile_url,
                    id=user.id,
                    access_token=user.access_token
                )
                return self.session.get("user")
        return None

    def dispatch(self):
        """
        This snippet of code is taken from the webapp2 framework documentation.
        See more at
        http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html
        """
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        try:
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        """
        This snippet of code is taken from the webapp2 framework documentation.
        See more at
        http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html
        """
        return self.session_store.get_session()


class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('example.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(dict(
            facebook_app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            current_user=self.current_user
        )))

    def post(self):
        url = self.request.get('url')
        file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(self.current_user['access_token'])
        response = graph.put_photo(file, "Test Image")
        photo_url = ("http://www.facebook.com/"
                     "photo.php?fbid={0}".format(response['id']))
        self.redirect(str(photo_url))


class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.current_user is not None:
            self.session['user'] = None

        self.redirect('/')

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__))
)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', HomeHandler), ('/logout', LogoutHandler)],
    debug=True,
    config=config
)
```

And here is the error:

> INFO 2015-03-29 22:18:30,182 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
>   500 - ERROR 2015-03-29 22:19:07,986 wsgi.py:263]  Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File
>   "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in
>   Handle handler = config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self.LoadHandler())
>   File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line
>   299, in _LoadHandler handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
>   File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line
>   85, in LoadObject obj = __import(path[0]) File
>   "/home/juliano/Documents/Projetos/Fb2/fb.py", line 1, in  import
>   facebook ImportError: No module named facebook INFO 2015-03-29
>   22:19:08,003 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I'm using these commands to add facebook python sdk:

```
virtualenv facebookenv
source facebookenv/bin/activate
pip install facebook-sdk
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not telling us how are you importing the library, so I assume you're treating it like other libraries, doing some sort of global install.

In GAE, you must have all the libraries you need in the same directory as your project, so they get uploaded alongside your code and can be accessed. Remember you run inside a sandbox and thus must take everything you need with you.

This means you need to download the `facebook` directory of the sdk and place it in the same directory where you have your `app.yaml`, and your `import` will be successful.

Comment: Sorry about it. Just added the commands to the original post.

Comment: Now the error is "ImportError: No module named requests". I suppose I should download it to my app install too, right?

Comment: Each time it asks for another library, now it's asking for requests.packages.urllib3.

Comment: You should read the docs, and look at all the other questions asking essentially the same thing.  This question is repeated an awful lot. You have to copy or link all 3rd party libs not included as part of the appengine runtime into your project and potentially manipulate sys.path depending how you achieve this.  This is documented!